# Should a JMS topic with no clients be automatically closed?

Tags: jms, hornetq, jboss-eap-6, jms-topic

I am trying to test a single component of a system that publishes messages to a JMS topic. It seems to run fine for a few hours before the connection is automatically closed and I get the following message in the log file:

> WARN  [org.hornetq.core.client] (hornetq-failure-check-thread) HQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: HQ119014: Did not receive data from invm:0. It is likely the client has exited or crashed without closing its connection, or the network between the server and client has failed. You also might have configured connection-ttl and client-failure-check-period incorrectly. Please check user manual for more information. The connection will now be closed. [code=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT]

Is this the correct behavior as there are no clients or should the topic continue to publish messages regardless of how many clients are connected?

Comment: The topic should continue to function normally.  This trace looks like it indicates that a CLIENT had a connection timeout and was closed, not the topic itself.

Comment: @jgitter That's what I thought. There was no consumer for the topic though.